# How can I convert this AJAX request function (raw Javascript) to use POST instead of GET?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, post, get

I was looking for AJAX in pure JavaScript (without jQuery) for learning purposes and came across this [video, along with the code (shown below)](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript-part-2--net-5220) on how to make one. However, it's geared towards `GET` method and I'm not sure how to tweak it to accept additional parameters so that the function can be used for either `POST` or `GET` depending on my specified parameters. For example, the lines `xhr.open('GET', url, true);` and `xhr.send('');` both are `GET`-specific (all other lines in the function are the same for both `GET` and `POST` methods)--I want to be able to be able to specify whether to use `POST` or `GET` as a parameter for `function load` for `xhr.open` and a string such as `"username="+username+"&password="+password` for `function load` for `xhr.send('');`

For example, the function below is for GET and is used like this `load('emails.php', function(xhr) {...}`. I want the function to be used like this: `` load('emails.php', 'POST', '"username="+username+"&password="+password' function(xhr) {...}` for POST and ``load('emails.php', 'GET', '', function(xhr) {...}`

The function for AJAX for GET:

```
function load(url, callback) {
    var xhr;

    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        var versions = ["Microsoft.XmlHttp",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0"];

        for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                break;
            }
            catch(e){}
        } // end for
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if((xhr.readyState < 4) || xhr.status !== 200) return;
        callback(xhr);
    };

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send('');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now the request body is set to null and ignored since you are making a GET request. You should just be able to put whatever you want sent in the body of the POST request inside of the send method:

```
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(someJsonHere));
```

Check out the [documentation for the xhr.send method here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

Here is also a link to a more thorough [guide on using XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest); at the bottom it has a section specific to sending data.

Comment: My title is incorrect--I am trying to find a way to add 2 additional parameters to the original function so that depending on the arguments, I can use the same function to perform either a GET or POST (example in the original post). I'm not looking to convert the function from GET to POST, just add support for POST. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure what the other parameter would be, but it seems like you could pass a parameter named method that would take either 'GET' or 'POST' as a string and use that string as the first parameter in xhr.open(). You could then also add a parameter named body that could be checked for undefined and then passed into xhr.send(). Hope that helps with your original intentions.